# How do you compare commit messages of two git branches to figure out the difference?

Tags: git

Let's say I have two branches: `release` and `master` I've cherry-picked some commits from master to release, and want to figure out which ones I've missed. I've tried to use `cherry`, but the commit in both branches (with a different hash) seems to still appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a rebase master to see what commits would actually be rebased.
A rebase shouldn't apply a commit whose content is already seen in another branch.

Another similar way is to look for the tree SHA1 of each commit in master, and see if there is a commit in release with a tree having the same SHA1

To access the tree SHA1 of a commit, use [`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse):

```
git rev-parse master~^{tree}
git rev-parse master~2^{tree}
git rev-parse master~3^{tree}
```